# Electrostatics - wire electric field symmetry

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

[image]

I was just wondering about the final part to do with the symmetry of the wire. In what circumstances would the wire not emit a field that's uniform? Would the wire have to be thick in some parts and thin in the others? If the wire was bent would it not be uniform?

Comment: In the moment when the wire is plugged in, current flows unevenly untill a steady current is reached. This is an example of non-uniform charge density. Also, external electric forces could mess with the uniformity.

Comment: In addition to Steeven, there wouldn't be a uniform electric field if the wire was not infinitely long. This is because more charges would be accumulated especially on the ends of the finite wire which would disturb the symmetry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wire is symmetrical if you can move any amount to the left and the right, and things look exactly the same. This means:

- there can be no current flowing in the wire (if there were, it would result in a changing electric field along the wire)
- there can be no non-uniform charge buildup on the wire (if there were, it would result in a current... see above)
- the wire must be of constant thickness
- the wire must be straight
- the wire must be infinitely long (otherwise, if you move to the end it no longer looks the same as everywhere else)

There may be other constraints one can think of - but this list should get you somewhere.

Note that it is possible to do similar things with wire loops - the equations change, but a wire that looks the same "regardless of what angle you rotate through" can be analyzed with very similar techniques as the one that looks the same "regardless of lateral shift".

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't understand how you cant have a current in the wire? Surely you need a current to produce the electric field in the first place?

Comment: You need a charge, not a current, to create the field. If you have a current, you break the left-right symmetry of the situation (need symmetry for both translation and reflection at all points). Put differently - the voltage to drive the current results in an electric field. Also it would no longer be electro**statics**